# Default Tag view in KeePass on startup

Tags: user-interface, keepass

I use categories to favourite some KeePass 2.x entries from various folders. With "Find Entries" for "Tag: Favourite" I can display those all at once. While KeePass will remember the last viewed folder, I can't get it to open back on to the tag view for those Favourites.

**Is there a way to automatically display entries for a specific tag on startup?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, this is actually possible by **defining** [**Triggers**](https://keepass.info/help/v2/triggers.html), One of the [examples](https://keepass.info/help/v2/triggers.html#examples) indeed covers this:

> Show entries by tag:
>
> Search all entries having the specified tag and show them in the entry list of the main window.

From **Tools**, **Triggers**, go to **Add** a new trigger.

Add a new trigger **Event "Opened database file"** . Optionally define a filter for a specific database file or path.

Add a new **Action "Show entries by tag"** and specify the tag you want to Default.

Give the Trigger a name, ensure it's Enabled and hit Finish. Whenever you open a database the main window will now automatically go to a Tag view.

As the Trigger System was [added with KeePass 2.x](https://keepass.info/compare.html), this is not possible in 1.x.